# Unexpected HTML from Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have some Razor code in a view that is supposed to route through to a different part of my model:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Journal", new { id = item.JOURNAL.REF_ID })
```

but when I look at the HTML that is emmitted, it is does not relect what I have written:

```
 <a href="/Reference/Edit?Length=7" id="25750">Edit</a>
```

How can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 4):

That's because you are using the wrong overload. It should be like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Journal", new { id = item.JOURNAL.REF_ID }, null)
```

Let's see why you are using the wrong overload. Let's break down what you wrote:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Edit",                              // linkText
    "Edit",                              // actionName
    "Journal",                           // routeValues
    new { id = item.JOURNAL.REF_ID }     // htmlAttributes
)
```

See the problem?

And now let's break down the correct way:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Edit",                              // linkText
    "Edit",                              // actionName
    "Journal",                           // controllerName
    new { id = item.JOURNAL.REF_ID },    // routeValues
    null                                 // htmlAttributes
)
```

See the difference?

I would recommend you reading very carefully the documentation and the [different available overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink.aspx) of the `ActionLink` helper as well as the exact significance of their parameters.

Comment: You're right - in fact I should RTFM!!  I think at the moment I'm just trying to get things working, reading tutorials and watching videos, but sometimes I miss finer details.